# Getting errors while building DNN Code in VS 2010

Tags: dotnetnuke

I am trying to run the dnn code in webmmatrix or VS 2010 both but getting the compile time error that- 
Unrecognized attribute 'requestValidationMode'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive.

Please suggest.

Comment: Are you trying to compile the Source of DNN itself? If you are trying to develop extensions, you can leave the source of DNN alone.

Comment: I am not creating any extensions. I've just taken the client's code and tried to set up on local environment. After compiling, i am getting this error.

Comment: You don't need to compile anything for DNN to run if they've provided you the files for the website.


Simply set IIS to point to the location where you have the code.

Comment: I've done the same, while pointing from IIS, getting the error- Unrecognized attribute 'requestValidationMode'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive. This is the line in the web.config -  <httpRuntime useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" maxRequestLength="8192" requestLengthDiskThreshold="8192" requestValidationMode="2.0"/>

Comment: We have received the public_html folder from the client. I've just point that folder to IIS and connecting with the restored local databse. Can you please suggest me

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the proper version of .NET installed, you'll want to install .NET 4.0 at the least, I would suggest all Windows Updates